# DNN Re-Index error: There is no build provider registered for the extension '.cshtml'

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke-8

I Upgraded DotNetNuke from version 8 to version 9.01.01 (116).

After the upgrade, I had a problem where all the users were not indexed.

The following process was followed in order to reindex the site:

1. The site was stopped in IIS.
2. All the files where deleted in `<Site>\App_Data\Search`
3. IIS Site was started
4. Re-index was done under site search -> settings
5. When searching the missing users where returned.

After the above, all the DNN MVC custom modules stopped working with the following error:

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException:
 There is no build provider registered for the extension '.cshtml'. You 
can register one in the <compilation><buildProviders> 
section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a 
BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web'
 or 'All'. ---> System.Web.HttpException: There is no build provider 
registered for the extension '.cshtml'. You can register one in the 
<compilation><buildProviders> section in machine.config or 
web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute
 which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.
   at 
System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetBuildProviderTypeFromExtension(CompilationSection
 config, String extension, BuildProviderAppliesTo neededFor, Boolean 
failIfUnknown)
   at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateBuildProvider(VirtualPath 
virtualPath, BuildProviderAppliesTo neededFor, CompilationSection 
compConfig, ICollection referencedAssemblies, Boolean failIfUnknown)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath 
virtualPath)
   at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
 virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean 
allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean 
ensureIsUpToDate)
   at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
 context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean 
allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, 
Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at 
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
 virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean 
throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath 
virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext 
viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at 
DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Framework.ActionResults.DnnViewResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
 context, TextWriter writer)
   at DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.MvcHostControl.RenderModule(ModuleRequestResult
 moduleResult)
   at DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.MvcHostControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I was using my google skills to the best of my knowledge.
Tried moving back the backed up search backed up files. Did not solve the problem.

Tried adding the item to the '.cshtml' without any success.

Comment: I restored a backed up version of the Site Tested locally did not have the same problems. When testing from the Server, I received the same result as previously indicated.
Thus the problem will be pointing to some (IIS setup/server) problem.
Investigating...

Comment: Site backup was restored and index rerun. The module problem was solved.  Thus indexing did not break the site.